# Cluster - a testing reading comprehension task. Which cluster does this word belongs?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

> Dr. Lefever believes that compulsive behaviour often manifests itself in *clusters*. There is, for example, the "eating disorder cluster," which also includes shopping and spending, work, cosmetic surgery, and exercise, *and the "relationship cluster" which includes compulsive helping of others, and addiction to love or being in love*. "If you are addicted to one thing in a cluster, you are at risk of becoming addicted to the others," he says.

Well, everything is clear except for this part:

> *and the "relationship cluster" which includes compulsive helping of others, **and addiction to love or being in love***.

I cannot understand the connection of this section (specially the highlighted part) with the rest of the text.
An addiction to love? Love what? Being in love?

What's happened to clusters?

> And there's a test:
>   Choose a, b or c from the options below.
>
> ● Dr. Lefever thinks that ____.
>
> a) if you are addicted to coffee, you might also become addicted to shopping
>
> b) if you have an eating disorder, you will probably become addicted to shopping
>
> c) if you are addicted to going to the gym, you may also become addicted to having cosmetic surgery.

I think *c* is the right answer, but "*eating disorder cluster*," which also includes *shopping* and ..." raises doubts about the option *b*.

Answer (score 3):

Think of the word "cluster" as simply jargon. The word might just as easily be group or even pattern. However "cluster" has the benefit of suggesting the closeness and commonality of the people in the grouping. But this is not a reference to a physical grouping, it is a virtual grouping; people who, depending on their addiction(s), can fall into one grouping or another.

So we have a "relationship cluster" - a grouping of people who share something in common, including "compulsive helping of others, and addiction to love or being in love".

You are uncertain about '*love what*', '*being in love*'? It's very important to remember that this is a discussion about genuine addiction, and the real and serious health and wellbeing consequences for an addict. You would do well to research on your own. I am not and do not claim to have a medical (or other) qualification in this area.
"**Love what**"?
My understanding is we are talking about loving other persons of the same or opposite sex.
"**being in love**"      My understanding is that this is the *experience* of loving and being in love. These are people who are addicted to the incredible highs of the first flush of love -  the initial lust and attraction stages. Typically lovers grow and develop, love becomes shared affection and the relationship itself changes. However people with love addiction seem to never get past the initial stages of falling in love; this gives them a sense of purpose and meaning. They become dependent on their objects of affection, hoping that these people will somehow complete their lives. This leads to complications about the choice of partner. (extracts from "[What is Love Addiction?](https://www.projectknow.com/research/love-addiction/)".)

The multiple choice question concerns grammar. I agree with your choice of option 'c'.

In recognising and describing the clusters, the Doctor does not say that addiction to one thing makes it *inevitable* that one will be or will become addicted to the other addictions of that cluster. Rather he describes a *higher **risk** of addiction* to the other addictions of the cluster.
So, the difference between option 'b' and 'c' is the difference between declaring the certainty or inevitability of addiction (you **will** become addicted) compared to recognising the the possibility or risk of addiction (you **may** become an addict).

Option 'b' is incorrect because the clusters do not dictate inevitability of further addiction.
Option 'c' is correct because the clusters describe risks of further addiction.

Answer (score 0):

[*Love*](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/love#love__8) is a feeling, and *being in love* is a state in which you experience certain feelings. The text implies you can become addicted to these feelings. That's it.

The first answer is wrong because coffee usually isn't consumed by eating (and an eating disorder isn't the same as a drinking one), and the second is wrong because *you will probably become addicted* is a lot stronger than *you are at risk of becoming addicted*.

The third answer is most likely correct: if you're addicted to going to the gym, you're probably addicted to exercise, which is in the same cluster as cosmetic surgery. *You may become addicted* expresses pretty much the same meaning as *you are at risk of becoming addicted* in this case.